# How to expand the size of UICollectionView when it is covering only part of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, mapkit

I have a `UIViewController` that has `MKMapView` in half of the screen and a `UICollectionView` in the other half of the screen. I would like the `MKMapView` to shrink and the `UICollectionView` to expand as I am scrolling up and `MKMapView` to appear back if I scroll down. Any advises?

Here is the photo of the desired screen view:

[image]

Comment: Are you using autoLayout ?

Comment: Yes I am using autoLayout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to make the mapView a part of the collectionView such as a headerView or a supplementaryView.

If you place both of them within the view of the view controller, then it won't be able to scroll. Though you can have a scrollview as a container and put the mapview view and collectionView within, it would be a pain to handle the scrolling.

So:
If you are using autoLayout, I would make the mapView either a header or a supplementary view of the collection.
If you are using frame structure, you can use a scrollview as the container and put both of them as subviews and do the maths yourself.

Comment: Yes that does make sense, Thank You!